# Model specific distance

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

One of the things that drew me to the Android Beacon Library was when I looked in the code I saw that distance calculations used a mode specific calculator.  However, when I look at http://data.altbeacon.org/android-distance.json it appears that there are only 3 models in the model map.  Is this correct?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Beacon distance accuracy is too flaky and effectively useless anyway, so I wouldn't look too much into the calculations. Consider the detection binary: Either a beacon was detected or it wasn't.

Comment: I disagree that limitations on accuracy make distance estimates useless.  People using them do need to have realistic expectations on accuracy and only use them if they are suitable for the use case.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the model database is paltry.

I am the one who set up this system, and I was hoping to get a number of submissions from the community for a wide variety of models.  Unfortunately, submissions have been very meagre, and my employer and consulting clients have been unwilling to sponsor labor hours needed to do the measurements and crunch the numbers on a wide variety of devices.

That said, the system is in place should you want to do the calculations for a specific model and get it added.

Comment: Well that's disappointing, because I also disagree with the commenter who said the distance calculation is useless.  Unfortunately I also don't have the time - or phone collection - to submit any data.